# If a US citizen were born on US military base abroad, would they be considered as born on US soil and thus eligible to be elected US president?

Tags: united-states, president, military, citizenship, election-requirements

As we know, the US Constitution provides that only a US citizen born on US soil can be elected US president. How about a hypothetical scenario of a US citizen born on a US military base abroad?

Comment: [John McCain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCain) born at "Coco Solo Naval Air Station in the Panama Canal Zone" and "entered the race for the Republican nomination for president in 2000".

Comment: "the US Constitution provides that only a US citizen born on US soil can be elected US president": that is incorrect.  It provides that only natural-born citizens can become president.  Eight decades later, it was amended to say that (nearly) everyone born in the US is a natural-born citizen.  But that never meant that those people were the _only_ natural-born citizens.

Comment: ...seven decades...

Comment: This paper considers this case and pretty much every other case you might care to consider https://scholarship.law.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1153&context=jcl

Comment: "As we know" in my experience is usually followed by an assertion of something incorrect. This one didn't disappoint. (Upvoted the answer of fellow Ted below)

Comment: There's the strange case of President Taft, who was born in Ohio, which due to a paperwork error never formally went through the full process of becoming a state but no one realized this until after Taft's death...

Comment: The question was also raised about Barry Goldwater (candidate in 1964), born in Arizona three years before statehood.

Answer (score 46):

Children born to US citizens are considered 'natural' US citizens regardless of where they are born. If US citizen has a child at an overseas military base, or in a foreign country, or even on Mars, there would be no constitutional obstacle to that child becoming president.

The question of 'US soil' only arises when a woman who is *not* a US citizen (or married to a US citizen) has a child. If that child is born on US soil it is considered a 'natural' citizen, if not, not. Military bases are not considered US soil in the same way that (say) an embassy or consulate is, so children born on a base to non-citizens are not automatically granted citizenship. They would have to be naturalized, which would bar them from being president.

Comment: US embassies and consulates in foreign countries are not US soil (and foreign embassies and consulates in the US are US soil).  See https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030101.html under "8 FAM 301.1-3  NOT INCLUDED IN THE MEANING OF "IN THE UNITED STATES"" item (c).

Comment: @phoog: Foreign embassies and consulates are *treated as* national soil for many purposes, but apparently not for conferring citizenship.  Good link, thanks for that.

Comment: The treatment is called "inviolability" in the Vienna Convention.  It's less a question of whose territory the premises are and more a provision that the host country can exercise its jurisdiction there only with the consent of the represented country.  But the jurisdiction nonetheless exists.

Comment: @phoog: No one with any political understanding thinks that the **actual land** a US embassy sits on belongs to the US, as though they might dig it up and cart it home when the embassy closes. In fact, the entire concept of 'national territory' is a *legal fiction* maintained by convention, treaty, and armed force. Saying that embassies are 'national soil' is merely an extension of that legal fiction, with (apparently) some limitation.

Comment: "Saying that embassies are 'national soil' is merely an extension of that legal fiction, with (apparently) some limitation": but this is not how the law currently views embassies.  An ambassador is both inviolable and immune from jurisdiction.  Premises of an embassy are only inviolable. The idea that embassies are the territory of the represented country is not a legal fiction but a popular misconception.  If a non-diplomat commits a crime in an embassy it is usually the host country that prosecutes, which would not be possible if embassies were truly extraterritorial.

Comment: @phoog: I don't think you're thinking through the concept of 'legal fiction'. Why do you think British police didn't pull Julian Assange out of the Ecuadorian Embassy in London, even though he was a wanted criminal? It's because Ecuador has sovereignty over its embassies, and British authorities have no jurisdiction there without Ecuadorian permission. But I don't see any reason to grind this discussion out, so let's just leave it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145850/discussion-between-phoog-and-ted-wrigley).

Comment: Could you please cite your sources? Especially that you make claims opposing those in the question.

Comment: @pajonk: phoog (despite our quibbles) gave a good source in his first comment; you can check that. On this site, I give sources where I think where I think it's helpful and/or necessary for context, otherwise I speak from general acumen and leave people to decide for themselves. To be honest, the current era abuses sourcing claims as a means of intellectual violence, and I'm a bit sour on all that. If I enjoyed pedantic, aggressive sourcing, I'd still be an academic.

Comment: Children born of US citizens are citizens ONLY if the parent has established US residency. The rule has terms and conditions, and has changed from time to time.

Comment: @TedWrigley https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4b1O.png

Comment: -1 this answer ignores all situations where having parent that is a US citizen does not give citizenship

Comment: For example: https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-h-chapter-3#footnotelink-19
This says that the parent needs to have stayed in the US for 5 years. 2 of those years when they are over 14 years old. Otherwise the child does not automatically gain citizenship.

Comment: @david "ONLY if the parent has established US residency": or if the child is born in the US, of course.  But it's not clear from your comment whether you mean to say that the residence must be current at the time of the birth.  It doesn't need to be. One parent must have had US residency at some point before the birth.  If Alice and Bob are both US citizens, but one of them was never in the US and the other moved from the US to another country at the age of one month, or even one day, their child will be a US citizen.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal the question is "when someone acquires US citizenship at birth and is born on a US military base, is that person natural-born?" So cases where someone is born on a US military base without acquiring US citizenship are not relevant to the question. That aside, the requirement to have resided in the US for five years of which two after age 14 applies only if the child's other parent is an alien; for the child of two US citizens there must only be prior residence, with no minimum duration specified. And military service abroad counts as residence in the US.

Comment: @phoog In current law, you need to have established residency to vote.  It doesn't matter what your current country of residence is. There is a bunch of stuff like that in American law.

Comment: @TedWrigley since embassies and consulates aren't considered US soil either (for the purposes of your 14th amendment), you may want to adjust your answer to reflect that; it currently implies that they _are_.

Comment: @david what does voting have to do with any of this?  One of the parents must have resided in the US at some point in the past; it does not matter where the parent resides at the time of birth or even if the parents are both without any fixed residence at the time of birth.  It doesn't matter whether the parent has ever voted or not in any election in the US or anywhere else.

Answer (score 30):

Military bases are not US soil; neither are US embassies or consulates.  Here's what the US State Department's Foreign Affairs Manual has to say about it ([8 FAM 301.1-3  NOT INCLUDED IN THE MEANING OF "IN THE UNITED STATES"](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030101.html)):

> c. Birth on U.S. military base outside of the United States or birth on U.S. embassy or consulate premises abroad:
>
> (1)  Despite widespread popular belief, U.S. military installations abroad and U.S. diplomatic or consular facilities abroad are not part of the United States within the meaning of the 14th Amendment.  A child born on the premises of such a facility is not born in the United States and does not acquire U.S. citizenship by reason of birth;
>
> (2)  The status of diplomatic and consular premises arises from the rules of law relating to immunity from the prescriptive and enforcement jurisdiction of the receiving State; the premises are not part of the territory of the United States of America.  (See Restatement (Third) of Foreign Relations Law, Vol. 1, Sec. 466, Comment a and c (1987).  See also, Persinger v. Iran, 729 F.2d 835 (D.C. Cir. 1984).

Furthermore, the foreign-born child of a US citizen normally acquires US citizenship at birth and therefore never needs to be naturalized and is therefore a natural-born US citizen eligible to be president.  There are those who argue otherwise, but they  generally rely on *The Law of Nations* by Vattel, which is not a direct source of US law, and ignore the fact that British law explicitly included foreign-born children of British subjects as "natural-born subjects."  They also ignore Vattel's assertion that foreign-born children follow the condition of the father unless the father has "fixed his domicile in a foreign country."

Comment: Two of my cousins were born in Berlin at the airport base a few years apart, about 10 years before the wall fell. Both parents were USAF sergeants, my cousins are both natural born citizens. That would have been a few years before the cited sources, so I would think that _when_ you were born probably matters for this discussion also.

Comment: @StingyJack foreign birth to US citizen parents has essentially always resulted in US citizenship, since the [Naturalization Act of 1790](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalization_Act_of_1790), provided that one of the parents has previously resided in the US. Details may have changed over the years (as they did for children born to a US citizen and an alien). But the question presupposes that the baby acquired US citizenship at birth ("if a US citizen were born on a military base abroad...").  People born on US bases who were later naturalized are clearly not natural-born citizens.

Comment: Children born of US citizens are citizens ONLY if the parent has established US residency. The rule has terms and conditions, and has changed from time to time.

Comment: @david the current law says that if both parents are US citizens then at least one must have "had a residence in the United States or one of its outlying possessions, prior to the birth."  My grandmother was born in the US although her family resided in London, yet my uncle, born in the Netherlands, was a US citizen from birth.  I had thought that this was because birth in the US is sufficient to establish residence in the US, but the Foreign Affairs Manual says evidence of residence is required, such as a birth certificate showing a US address. Maybe my grandmother's b.c. had a US address.

Comment: Downvote... why?

Comment: @phoog The law has changed. Don't know what the law was for your Uncle, but present law would not have applied.

Comment: @david that is correct, but the requirement of prior residence was the same. I was under the impression that (1) she had never resided in the US but (2) a court had ruled that physical presence would satisfy the residence requirement.  When I looked for the court ruling, I found instead that the government says that physical presence _doesn't_ satisfy the residence requirement, which implies that I was wrong about (1).  Then I found the text in the FAM, which was the source of my misconception about (2) because I had remembered it somewhat wrongly.

Comment: So a US citizen born in London, moved to the USA aged 10, moved back to London aged 15, would have "had a residence in the USA", and their child born in London would also be US citizen?

Comment: @gnasher729 if the child's other parent is also a US citizen, yes, because the controlling subsection is 8 USC 1401(c).  If the other parent is a non-citizen US national then the birth falls under 1401(d), which has no residence requirement but a 1-year physical presence requirement, which is met in this case, so the child would be a US citizen. If the other parent is an alien then the relevant subsection is 1401(g), and there is a 5-year physical presence requirement of which two years after age 14, which is not met here, so the child would not be a US citizen.

Answer (score 10):

Well, Wikipedia says of the best known example (mentioned in a comment):

> Had he been elected, [John McCain] would have become the first president physically born outside the United States. This raised a potential legal issue, since the United States Constitution requires the president to be a natural-born citizen of the United States. A bipartisan legal review, and a unanimous but non-binding Senate resolution, both concluded that he was a natural-born citizen. However, other legal scholars came to the opposite conclusion that although he was a citizen, at the time of his birth he was not a natural born citizen; that is because the 1937 law that made him a citizen was passed one year after his birth.

Which cites a [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/11/world/americas/11iht-11mccain.14411311.html) for those inclined to pursue this. So, the political will was there to declare McCain eligible, but who knows what might happen in a different case, as circumstances would probably not be 100% identical (given that that law was [specific](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030204.html) to Panama--see 8 FAM 302.4).

I.e. it's possible for someone to be made retroactively a citizen by law. Whether that would also satisfy the judicial branch for the purpose of making someone ["natural born Citizen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-born-citizen_clause_(United_States)) is not entirely clear (because that issue is rather untested in courts)... but Wikipedia also says:

> The U.S. Constitution uses but does not define the phrase "natural born Citizen" and various opinions have been offered over time regarding its exact meaning. The consensus of early 21st-century constitutional and legal scholars, together with relevant case law, is that natural-born citizens include, subject to exceptions, those born in the United States. As to those born elsewhere who meet the legal requirements for birthright citizenship, the consensus emerging as of 2016 was that they also are natural-born citizens.

For the latter it references a legal challenge to Ted Cruz, [dismissed](https://apnews.com/article/347bc50100614e64989d2a3d73665367) by the Supreme Court of Pennsylvania in 2016:

> Texas Sen. Ted Cruz has won a case in Pennsylvania’s highest court that had challenged his eligibility to appear on the state’s GOP primary ballot and serve as president.
>
> The state Supreme Court order Thursday upheld a lower-court judge’s decision to dismiss the case.
>
> A Pittsburgh resident and registered Republican voter, Carmon Elliott, had argued that Cruz isn’t eligible to run for president or to appear on Pennsylvania’s April 26 primary ballot because he was born in Canada.
>
> Commonwealth Court Judge Dan Pellegrini ruled March 11 that common law precedent and statutory history maintain that **an eligible candidate includes any person born to an American citizen, regardless of where**.
>
> Elliott had acknowledged that Cruz’s mother was born in the United States and has been a U.S. citizen her whole life.

But, of course, another judge in some other US state could rule differently, with SCOTUS as the ultimate arbiter.

Comment: FWIW the 1937 law was not in fact retroactive.  It "declared" the US citizenship of certain people born in the Canal Zone, but it did not say anything explicitly about when that citizenship came into existence, which implies that it came into existence when the law took effect.

Comment: @phoog: my reading of those sources is that it *was* made retroactive back to 1904. "Additionally, this Act was retroactive to February 26, 1904 "Isthmian Canal Convention."" & "because the 1937 act applies retroactively" in the FAM.

Comment: Read the act; it doesn't say anything about retroactive application.  The question would come up if someone born in the CZ had never been naturalized and then had a child with a US citizen in another foreign country before 1937.  Does that child gain US citizenship on the passage of the act?  If not, the grant of citizenship isn't truly retroactive.

Comment: Even when a law mentions "retroactive application", it does not mean that it makes the citizenship retroactive. For example, section 101 of the [Immigration and Nationality Technical Corrections Act of 1994](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/103/hr783/text) has "retroactive application", but what the text really says is that the nationality laws will be applied "as though" the law had been in effect originally. I interpret this to mean that it only alters the consequences of the laws (e.g. transmitting citizenship) from this point forward, but doesn't actually make the law retroactive.

Comment: I agree that there's nothing in the text of the 1937 act that implies that it's retroactive, but I'm not a lawyer and I don't know whether retroactivity is allowed to be inferred from the intent of the drafters. I'm guessing the Citizenship Clause in the 14th amendment is considered retroactive, even though it doesn't say so.

Comment: Also, with respect to people who would have been born with US citizenship if they had been born outside the US more generally, it's plausible to interpret the 1937 act as a mere clarification, implying that McCain would have been a natural-born citizen even without that act; see https://repository.law.umich.edu/mlr_fi/vol107/iss1/19/

Comment: Though the 1937 act certainly had substantive effect at least in the case of people born in the Canal Zone whose parents did *not* meet the usual residence requirements to transmit citizenship, because the 1937 act does not require either parent to have ever resided in the US, whereas the usual rules on transmitting citizenship to foreign-born children do.

Comment: @Brian excellent points all. I'll have another look at it at some point, but I've been having trouble establishing exactly which statute applied to foreign-born children of two US citizens in 1936. On the 14th amendment, similar to the CZ act, the question would be whether, for example, a child born outside the US before the 14th amendment, whose parents were born in the US without acquiring US citizenship (whether because they were enslaved, or Chinese, or for another reason other than diplomatic immunity) would have been considered a US citizen on the passage of the amendment. I suspect not.

Comment: @Brian if I am right about that then in that respect the 14th amendment was not retroactive.  It granted US citizenship to people born before it took effect but it did not erase the period of non-citizenship that existed between their birth and that day.  Also, back to McCain, I suppose someone should check the debate records to see whether they really were concerned about the "outside the limits but not the jurisdiction" argument, as some modern writers claim, or only about the residence requirement issue that you raise.

Answer (score 9):

> As we know, the US Constitution provides that only a US citizen born on US soil can be elected US president.

False, there is no provision of the US Constitution that clearly states such a requirement.

What it *actually* provides for is that

> No Person except a natural born Citizen, […] shall be eligible to the Office of President;

The Constitution did not come with a glossary, and the founders did not define for us exactly what “natural born Citizen” meant to them. *One interpretation* says that it means “a US citizen born on US soil,” but that is not the only interpretation of the phrase. Children born abroad can be born with US citizenship in some circumstances,¹ meaning they were born with that citizenship and so might—or might not—count as a “natural born Citizen […] of the United States” as required by the Constitution.

In the absence of clarity in the Constitution itself, this issue would have to be settled by the courts. To date, it has not been fully settled once and for all, but we have some information to go on: at least two people who have run for president have had questionable claim to being “natural born Citizen[s],” John McCain (born on a US military base to two US-citizen parents) and Ted Cruz (born in Canada to a US-citizen mother).

John McCain’s case is arguably the more relevant of the two, since he was actually born on an overseas military base, just as in the question. However, there are a lot of particular details in his case that are not necessarily relevant today—the fact that he was born specifically in a US military base in the Panama Canal Zone is significant, as is the fact that his citizenship was derived from a 1937 law—passed a year *after* he was born. Moreover, no court ruled on the matter—Congress passed a non-binding resolution acknowledging his qualification to be president, but the legal challenges that were made got dismissed for procedural reasons. Had McCain been elected, it is likely that the matter would finally be put before the Supreme Court.

Ted Cruz’s situation actually saw at least one court rule on the matter, though since it was not the Supreme Court, it could still be challenged. In his case, Cruz was unaware of his dual Canadian citizenship right until 2014; he renounced that citizenship and none of the numerous challenges to his candidacy prevailed. In each case, the ruling by the court or board or whatever was that the fact he had US citizenship from birth—even though he was born in Canada and also had Canadian citizenship from birth—meant he met the Constitutional requirements to be president.

1. <sub>See [Acquisition of U.S. Citizenship at Birth by a Child Born Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Acquisition-US-Citizenship-Child-Born-Abroad.html) from the State Department.</sub>

Comment: The critical fact of McCain's case is not that he was born on a military base but that he was born in the Canal Zone.  The legal situation would have been the same if he had been born anywhere else in the Canal Zone.  Had he been born outside the Canal Zone, whether on a US military base or not, he would have been a US citizen from birth.

Comment: @phoog Point, missed a key word there.

Comment: But it's not just _overseas;_ it's specifically _in the Canal Zone._ If he had been born in a military base in any other place, such as the Philippines, or in foreign territory (if such a thing had existed at the time), there would have been no issue.

Comment: And indeed of he had been born anywhere abroad, _outside_ the Canal Zone, and _not_ on a military base, there would have been no issue.  Also, the law was not explicitly retroactive, but people don't seem to dwell on that.

Comment: @phoog Hm, didn’t realize all of that. My primary impetus for answering this question was to state explicitly that the premise in the question was wrong, which at the time of writing, no answer had done. I tried to make it a complete answer, but the intricacies of the John McCain case are clearly more involved than I realized. I’ll edit to just allude to the fact that it was complicated and leave it at that.

Comment: Well my answer does point out that the premise of the question is wrong; it just addresses a different incorrect element of the premise. :-) I only learned of the Canal Zone's unique status because of this question. People typically assume that his case was complicated because he was born abroad on a military base, but in fact it's because the CZ wasn't part of the US for 14th amendment purposes but it was also not "out of the limits and jurisdiction of the United States," the phrase used in the "normal" foreign-birth statute. The 1937 law fixed this by addressing births in the Canal Zone.

Comment: "as is the fact that his citizenship was derived from a 1937 law" This is disputed, and is one of the key disputes in his case. Some interpretations say that he acquired citizenship at birth through the law that applies to people born abroad. For example, [INS interpretations 301.1(b)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118060326/http://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-45104/0-0-0-45113.html#0-0-0-23041)(2) says "Under the above rules, a child acquired citizenship at birth in [...] the Canal zone (before August 4, 1937)"

Comment: @user102008 I find that document very unclear.  It's not obvious what specific rules it's referring to.  If the State Department was at the time refusing to grant passports to children in McCain's circumstances then it would be difficult to argue that he had US citizenship at birth.  And as far as I've seen, reason for the 1937 law is that the state department was indeed refusing to issue US passports to children born in McCain's circumstances. Also the significance of the dates is different for different territories, and some are just incorrect: ...

Comment: ...Alaska was still Russian on March 30 1867; it was transferred on October 17th.  Similarly, the dates for Hawaii and the USVI are the dates on which the US assumed jurisdiction over these territories.  But the US acquired the CZ in 1904.  It therefore has this period between 1904 and 1937 when it was not "abroad" (since the nationality law uses the phrase "out of the limits and jurisdiction" and the CZ was under US jurisdiction), and the INS document does not address this at all.  Given other signs of carelessness in the document, I would suspect that this is also the result of carelessness.

Comment: @phoog: [8 FAM 302.1-2](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030201.html#M302_1_2).b seems to agree with this interpretation though: "Before the Nationality Act of 1940 and absent laws specifying how U.S. citizenship could be acquired by persons born in a particular territory, children born in a U.S. possession could acquire U.S. citizenship under the laws governing birth abroad if the citizen parent was qualified to transmit U.S. citizenship." Though it's also not explained what the legal basis of this interpretation is.

Comment: @user102008 well, now I'm really curious.  I should make the time to find the congressional record.  I suppose it's difficult to pin down because there are so few cases where it would make a difference; the question is mostly academic.  If, as I read somewhere, the CZ was in 1937 the only territory without a particular law applying to it (and assuming that similar laws for other territories were all passed more quickly), then the only people it would make a difference for would be certain grandchildren of US citizens and potentially presidential candidates.